# Regex match reverse of a group in a string

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I need to match a group at the start of a string with the reverse of group at the end. 
Ex:
`batmantab` would match because `bat` and `tab`.
`racecar` would match because `rac` and `car`.

current regex:

```
'^(\w{3})\w*\1$'
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You need to capture each character separately.

```
^(\w)(\w)(\w)\w*\3\2\1$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cF9oW4/1)

But it's impossible to reverse a group which contains two or more characters through regex.

```
$ grep -oP '^(\w)(\w)(\w)\w*\3\2\1$' file2
batmantab
racecar
$ grep -o '^\(\w\)\(\w\)\(\w\)\w*\3\2\1$' file2
batmantab
racecar
```